# Elasticsearch client: speed up client creation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I am developing integration tests with elasticsearch. At the beginning I instantiate the client like this:

```
Settings settings = Settings.EMPTY;
Client client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
                .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost", "9300"));
```

The elasticsearch server is embedded into a docker container, with following environment variables:

```
- cluster.name=elasticsearch
- "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
- xpack.security.enabled=false
- xpack.monitoring.enabled=false
- xpack.graph.enabled=false
- xpack.watcher.enabled=false
```

At each test run, it takes up to 20s just for client creation.

Is there anyway to speed it up?
Thx.

Comment: reuse the same client for all tests. Client creation should be immediate, are you sure it's not waiting for es service to become avaiable?

Comment: I personaly prefer use the RestHighLevelClient, it seems faster, and the transport client is deprecated.